# Cannot instantiate the type Parent

Tags: java, types, instantiation

I dont know why i keep getting this error:

in my method I have:

```
int option;
Object message[] = new Object[6];      
message[0] = firstName;
message[1] = txtfirstName;
message[2] = lastName;
message[3] = txtlastName;
message[4] = gender;
message[5] = txtgender;


int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,message,"Register a Person",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION ,                                                            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

Parent parent = new Parent(txtfirstName.getText(),txtlastName.getText(),txtgender.getText());   
            creche.add(parent);`
```

in my main I have setup:

`ArrayList<Parent> parent = new ArrayList<Parent>();
        List<Person> school = new ArrayList<Person>();`

```
MyApp app = new MyApp ();
    `
```

And I have subclass parent and child and superclass Person.

ERROR: `Parent parent = new Parent(var1,var2,var3,var4);`

But this works: `Child child = new Child(var1,var2,var3,var4);

                creche.add(child);`

Any help?

Comment: Is the Parent class abstract?

Comment: Yep it was :) its now working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this to work the Parent class needs to be defined as a concrete class.

E.g.

```
public class Parent extends Person {

}
```

I am guessing it is defined as an Abstract Class or interface. (See below)

E.g.

```
public interface Parent {

}

public abstract Class Parent  {

}
```

You probably just need to declare it as a concrete class as above.

Comment: This is the starting of it:

Comment: This is the start of it: public abstract class Parent extends Person{
 List<Child> child;
 

 public Parent(){
  
 
 this.child = new ArrayList<Child>();
 }
 
 public Parent(String firstName, String lastName, String gender)
 {

Comment: Delete the word abstract in the Parent definition  (as per my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Abstract or Interfaces cannot be instantiated.  Only child classes can be